# Overriding assignment of value in Lua

Tags: c, lua

I am using Lua v5.2.2 within a C application (embedded environment/MCU).

I need to expose some "parameters" in Lua, that for reading and writing you need to directly access the hardware (thus a C call is needed). I am looking however for other means to implement this than using plain old getters and setters.

I am mostly exploring the meta-programming power of Lua, but also I believe I can create a simpler interface for the user.

What I want to achieve is behaviour like the following:

```
my_param = createParameter{name="hw_param1", type="number", min=0, max=100}

my_param = 5

result = my_param + 3
```

On the first line a new parameter is created. This is a call towards a C function. Userdata is pushed to stack with a properly initialized struct. The hardware is also initialized as needed. A new table is returned.

On the second line an assignment is done to the parameter object. I want this to call a C function with a single argument (that of the assignment), so the value can be stored to the hardware registers.

On the third line the parameter is read. I again need a call towards a C function that will get the value of the parameter from the hardware registers, and that will return the result.

Note that the actual value of this parameter may change outside the scope of Lua, so reading the value once during initialization is not correct. The C function must be called each time to get the actual value. Similarly writing to the value must cause an immediate write to the hardware.

How can I accomplish this? Specifically can I alter the metatable of the parameter to achieve lines 2 and 3? (I am aware of how to implement line 1).

Also is it necessary to return a table from the constructor? May I, for example, return a primitive Lua type (e.g. a number) that will behave like above?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can modify the metatable metamethods.

Line 2 would completely change the variable's value that it holds.

However, if you were to set a field in the parameter object like: `my_param.x = n`, the `__newindex` metamethod would get invoked; which you could overwrite the metamethod to behave as you would like. In your case you would make it set the parameter's field and update it with a C function call.

Regarding line 3, same principle applies, instead this time you would just use the `__add` metamethod, and manipulate the object when `__add` is invoked.

http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetamethodsTutorial

Comment: Not exactly what I am asking for. Essentially I want my_param = n to call a function instead of making an assignment. Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible, but kind of weird. See the edit to my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you're asking for, but it's close:

```lua
function createParameter(t)
  param = {}
  param.data = t
  backingTable = {}
  metatable = {}
  function metatable.__index(t, k)
    -- You can intercept the value here if you 
    -- want and pass it on to your C fuction.
    return backingTable[k]
  end
  function metatable.__newindex(t, k, v)
    -- You can intercept the value here if you 
    -- want and pass it on to your C fuction.
    backingTable[k] = v
  end
  setmetatable(param, metatable)
  return param
end

--------------------------------------------------------

my_param = createParameter{name="hw_param1", type="number", min=0, max=100}

my_param.value = 5

result = my_param.value + 3

print(result) -- prints 8
print(my_param.data.name) -- prints hw_param1
```

You might be able to do something tricky by assigning a metatable to the global table `_G`, but I think that would be kind of tricky to get set up right and could lead to unexpected outcomes.

Edit:

If you really hate having to have a level of indirection, and you really want to be able to set it directly, here's how you can do it by setting the global table.

```
globalMetatable = {}
globalParamNames = {}
globalParams = {}
function globalMetatable.__index(t, k)
  if globalParamNames[k] then
    -- You can intercept the value here if you 
    -- want and pass it on to your C fuction.
    print("Read from param " .. k)
    return globalParams[k]
  else 
    rawget(_G, k)
  end
end
function globalMetatable.__newindex(t, k, v)
  if globalParamNames[k] then
    -- You can intercept the value here if you 
    -- want and pass it on to your C fuction.
    print("Wrote to param " .. k)
    globalParams[k] = v
  else
    rawset(_G, k, v)
  end
end
setmetatable(_G, globalMetatable)

function createParameter(t)
  globalParamNames[t.varname] = true
end

--------------------------------------------------------

createParameter{varname="my_param", name="hw_param1", type="number", min=0, max=100}

my_param = 5

result = my_param + 3

print(result) -- prints 8
print(my_param) -- prints 5
```